# liferay spring mvc AnnotationFormatterFactory

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay

Using liferay 6.0.x I am trying to register a custom AnnotationFormatterFactory to my spring mvc portlet but it doesn't use it to convert my pojo attributes.
Here my code :

My annotation:

```
@Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ListSelector {

    public enum ListSelectorType {
        UTILISATEURS
    }

    ListSelectorType type();
    boolean useReferentiel() default true;

}
```

My Formatter :

```
public class ListSelectorUtilisateurFormater implements Formatter<List> {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ListSelectorUtilisateurFormater.class);

    public ListSelectorUtilisateurFormater() {
    }

    @Override
    public String print(final List listeUtilisateurs, final Locale locale) {
        try {
            return ConvertJSONUtilForListSelector.convertUserToJSON(listeUtilisateurs).toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            ListSelectorUtilisateurFormater.LOG.error("error formatting user list to JSON", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List parse(final String formatted, final Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        List<String> extractedIds;
        List<Utilisateur> users = new ArrayList<Utilisateur>();
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(formatted)) {
            extractedIds = Arrays.asList(formatted.split(","));
                // génére une liste d'utilisateurs n'ayant que des ids
                for (final String id : extractedIds) {
                    final Utilisateur user = new Utilisateur();
                    user.setId(id);
                    users.add(user);
                }
        }
        return users;
    }

}
```

My AnnotationFormatterFactory:

```
public class ListSelectorFormatterFactory implements AnnotationFormatterFactory<ListSelector> {

    private final Set<Class<?>> fieldTypes;

    public ListSelectorFormatterFactory(
                UtilisateurService utilisateurService) {

        Set<Class<?>> rawFieldTypes = new HashSet<Class<?>>(1);
        rawFieldTypes.add(List.class);
        this.fieldTypes = Collections.unmodifiableSet(rawFieldTypes);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes() {

        return this.fieldTypes;
    }

    @Override
    public Printer<?> getPrinter(ListSelector annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {

        return configureFormatterFrom(annotation, fieldType);
    }

    @Override
    public Parser<?> getParser(ListSelector annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {

        return configureFormatterFrom(annotation, fieldType);
    }

    private Formatter<?> configureFormatterFrom(ListSelector annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {

        switch (annotation.type()) {
            case UTILISATEURS:
                        return new ListSelectorUtilisateurFormater();
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

}
```

My pojo (I have tried native spring annotation to but they doidn't work too):

```
public class Pojo {

    @ListSelector(type= ListSelector.ListSelectorType.UTILISATEURS)
    private List<Utilisateur> test = new ArrayList<Utilisateur>();

    @ListSelector(type= ListSelector.ListSelectorType.UTILISATEURS)
    private Utilisateur[] test2;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
    private Date date;

    public List<Utilisateur> getTest() {
       return test;
    }

    public void setTest(List<Utilisateur> test) {
       this.test = test;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

And finally my applicationContext.xml (I have tried the mcv:annotation-driven and the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter approach):

None of the pjo annotation worked in my jsp :

```
[${testPojo.date}][<spring:eval expression="testPojo.date" />][<spring:bind path="testPojo.date">${status.value}</spring:bind>]<br/>
            [${testPojo.test}][<spring:eval expression="testPojo.test" />][<spring:bind path="testPojo.test">${status.value}</spring:bind>]<br/>
```

The first [] give me the List Reference or the Not formatted date, the second and the third give me nothing.

Anyone got any idea how to use AnnotationFormatterFactory or standart spring formatter in liferay ?